# How can I follow a Django reverse-foreign-key and then another reverse-foreign-key?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Suppose I have 3 Django models:

mymodela/models.py:

```
class MyModelA(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()
    created_ts = models.DateTimeField()
```

mymodelb/models.py:

```
from mymodela.models import mymodela
class MyModelB(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()
    my_a = models.ForeignKey(MyModelA, related_name="MyModelB_a")
    created_ts = models.DateTimeField()
```

mymodelc/models.py:

```
from mymodelb.models import MyModelB
class MyModelC(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()
    my_b = models.ForeignKey(MyModelB, related_name="MyModelC_b")
    created_ts = models.DateTimeField()
```

I have an instance of `MyModelA` called `a`. I would like to calculate this QuerySet:

```
MyModelC.objects.filter(my_b__my_a=a).latest("created_ts")
```

However, I need to calculate this queryset from within a method of `a`. And since `MyModelA` doesn't import `MyModelC`, I cannot do that directly. I need to follow the reverse links. But how can I follow the reverse links twice to get what I need?

Comment: Why can you not import `MyModelC` in your `MyModelA` method and run the query that you have already specified above?

Comment: Importing `MyModelC` in `MyModelA` would cause a circular dependency. Right?

Comment: No - let me post an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `mymodela/models.py` (by the way, I'm not sure why you have separated all your models into separate directories like this - unless this is deliberate you might consider putting them all in your app's `models.py` file):

```
class MyModelA(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()
    created_ts = models.DateTimeField()

    # A method that will fetch the most recent related MyModelC 
    def get_latest_c(self):
        from mymodelc.models import MyModelC
        return MyModelC.objects.filter(my_b__my_a=self).latest("created_ts")
```

Now when you have some instance of `MyModelA` called `a`, you call `a.get_latest_c()` to get the most recent related `MyModelC` object.

Comment: As suspected, adding `from mymodelc.models import MyModelC` gave me an import error: https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/f8319ab6c474edbe6bc4

Comment: That is a different issue altogether - a failure to import `MyModelA` from your `mymodelb/models.py`. If you post the complete code you are using then it will be easier to track down the error.

Comment: No. It's not a different issue. The code was running fine without that single line I inserted. When I inserted that line, this error appeared. And it makes sense: mymodelb/models.py can no longer import MyModelA, because myModelA now imports MyModelC which imports MyModelB which imports MyModelA, and on and on forever. Here is my actual code. Please feel free to play with it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1UFylbhbG2eWDd3NEdPQkU2OFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So, do the import within the get_latest_c method.

Comment: Or, declare all your models in one file instead of in three separate files.

Comment: The models belong to different Django applications within the same project. So they cannot all be placed into a single file.

Comment: Daniel's suggestion worked. Thanks! But it still feels like a bit of a hack because it looks like it breaks all the rules of OOP. Is there some way I could create a method in MyModelB and call it from `a` using the related name? And then have that method call a static method in MyModelC through its related_name? That might not be possible. But it would "feel" better.

Comment: I can't see how you would travel up the related names because when you go that way you get a `RelatedManager` (i.e, there could be multiple related objects, it is a one to many relationship) and you would have to iterate over that before you can get to the next level. What you could do is move the `get_latest_c` method out of the model and into (depending on how you use it) a template tag. This would avoid the import issue.